# Ever had LED bulbs cause AFCI tripping?

Tags: electrical, led, afci

I replaced a 50W halogen gu10 bulb in a ceiling fixture on an AFCI-protected circuit with a 5W dimmable LED bulb, and it trips the breaker after a few seconds (even after reseating the bulb). Another brand of non-dimmable LED bulb worked fine. (light is not on a dimmer.) Do people think the problem is a defective bulb, or nuisance tripping?

Comment: All GU10 I know is 110/120v so 5W @ 110V is ~.05 Amp. So 1/20 Amp tripping a 15? Amp breaker is a problem.

Comment: Can you find another brand/model of dimmable LED bulb to test with? I suspect that it's indeed a nuisance trip scenario, perhaps aggravated by certain LED bulb designs.